# Why is my MongoDB Database Server failing to start with the 'Unrecognized option: storage.journal.enabled' error, and how can I resolve it?

Tags: mongodb

```
× mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-10-18 10:42:27 UTC; 20min ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Main PID: 6847 (code=exited, status=2)
CPU: 32ms

Oct 18 10:42:27 ip-CENSORED systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Oct 18 10:42:27 ip-CENSORED mongod[6847]: Unrecognized option: storage.journal.enabled
Oct 18 10:42:27 ip-CENSORED mongod[6847]: try ‘/usr/bin/mongod --help’ for more information
Oct 18 10:42:27 ip-CENSORED systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, stat>
Oct 18 10:42:27 ip-CENSORED systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result ‘exit-code’.
```

Someone could help me?

I've tried to restart, i checked the logs and conf and nothing happened

Comment: This probably belongs on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ rather than here. In any case, a quick search reveals [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage-options) that seems to be pretty clear: "_Changed in version 6.1: MongoDB always enables journaling. As a result, MongoDB removes the `storage.journal.enabled` option_" Sounds like the solution is to remove that argument from the config file

Comment: Commented storage.journal.enabled and reboot the server works for me. Thanks